# How to make my data types independent of compiler in c

Tags: c, embedded, rtos, ucos

I was studying uC/OS and read this article:

> Because different microprocessors have different **word length**, the port
>   of μC/OS-II includes a series of type definitions that ensures
>   portability Specifically, **μC/OS-II’s code never makes use of C’s
>   short, int and, long data types because they are inherently
>   non-portable.** Instead, I defined integer data types that are both
>   portable and intuitive as shown in listing 1.1. Also, for convenience,
>   I have included floating-point data types even though μC/OS-II doesn’t
>   make use of floating-point. The following is listing 1.1

```
typedef unsigned char BOOLEAN;
typedef unsigned char INT8U;
typedef signed char INT8S;
typedef unsigned int INT16U;
typedef signed int INT16S;
typedef unsigned long INT32U;
typedef signed long INT32S;
typedef float FP32;
typedef double FP64;
#define BYTE INT8S
#define UBYTE INT8U
#define WORD INT16S
#define UWORD INT16U
#define LONG INT32S
#define ULONG INT32U
```

My questions is :

1- What does the writer mean by word length(the first bold words in my question body) ?!

2- Why short int and long data types are inherently non-portable.

3- Is `typedef` is a microprocessor directive, and if it is what is its function ?!

4- Can I write `typedef unsigned char (anything)` instead of `typedef unsigned char INT8U;`

5- Why did the author code `typedef unsigned char INT8U;` and then `#define UBYTE INT8U`
   can't I use this directly `typedef unsigned char UBYTE;`

6- There is a double use of `typedef unsigned char` one of them is `typedef unsigned char INT8U;` and the other `typedef unsigned char BOOLEAN;` Why did he do that?!

Comment: Would you please answer question 5 and 6 too ! @goldilocks

Comment: 5- I wouldn't read too much into the author's technique here.  It's just a matter of person preference.  The author used typedef to define fixed width data types and then used macros to associate another set of terms (BYTE, WORD, etc.) with the fixed width data types.  Yes, you could use typedef to define BYTE and WORD if that's your preference.

Comment: 6- The author wanted to define data types for an 8-bit wide variable and a Boolean (single bit) because either could be required for any particular software abstraction.  He plans to write code at a level of abstraction higher than the base data type.  So when his code requires a TRUE/FALSE variable he will use Boolean.  And when his code requires an 8-bit variable he will use INT8U.  Both these types happen to be the same underneath but using the abstract types adds more meaning to the source code.  When you review his code and see a Boolean you will know it is a TRUE/FALSE variable.

Comment: Looks like I did that at the same time (added below) -- but kkrambo is a little more succinct.

Comment: I strongly suggest using the C99 stdint.h typedefs; those are defined for your particular target's compiler and architecture rather than relying on someone else's port. I'd be tempted to redefine all the uC/OS-II types in terms of stdint.h types, so you need never do it again. You could then safely use the types interchangeably avoiding the need for ugly capitalised type names. Apart from that every library you are likely to come across will think it a good idea to define integer types with remarkably similar (or identical) names to these and the chances of name clash are high - avoid!

Comment: Further; us stdbool.h rather than some third-party library boolean definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1- What does the writer mean by word length

A word is a fundamental unit of memory like [a page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_%28computer_memory%29) -- actually, there's an article [on word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29) too, which I won't regurgitate.  The significance to C is, like your author says, that it is not always the same but it is determined by hardware characteristics.  This maybe one reason the C standard doesn't dictate the literal size of basic types; the most obvious one to contemplate is the size of pointers, which will be 4 bytes on 32-bit systems and 8 on 64-bit systems, to reflect the size of the address space.

> 2- Why short int and long data types are inherently non-portable.

More accurately: they're as portable as C *but* their size is not standardized, which may make them useless for many applications where a fixed specific size is required.

> 3- Is typedef is a microprocessor directive, and if it is what is its function ?!

No, it's not a processor directive.  It's a nice piece of [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) which enables you to define custom types.

> 4- Can I write typedef unsigned char (anything) instead of typedef unsigned char INT8U;

Yep, that's the idea.  Beware that the C standard doesn't even dictate the size of a char, although I've never heard of an implementation where it is anything but 8-bits *[but someone in the comments has]*.

> 5- Why did the author code typedef unsigned char INT8U; and then #define UBYTE INT8U can't I use this directly typedef unsigned char UBYTE;

You could, yes.  Possibly the author wanted to restrict the number of places such a type is defined.  Since using the `#define` is a pre-processor directive, it might also also slightly streamline the executable (although not to a degree that could be considered generally significant).

> 6- There is a double use of typedef unsigned char one of them is typedef unsigned char INT8U; and the other typedef unsigned char BOOLEAN; Why did he do that?!

Again, use of typedefs is a lot about "sugar"; they can make your code cleaner, easier to read, and (presuming they are done properly), more robust.  "Boolean" is a math derived CS term for a type which only has two meaningful values, zero (false) or not zero (true).  So it could in theory be implemented with just one bit, but that's neither easy nor in the end efficient (because there are no processors with 1-bit registers, they would have to slice dice and fake such anyway).  Defining a "bool" or "boolean" type is common in C and used to indicate that the significance of the value is either true or false -- it works well with, e.g. `if (var)` (true) and `if (!var)` (false) since C already evaluates that way (0 and NULL are the only values that will pass `if (!var)`).  Whereas using something like `INT8U` indicates you are dealing with a value that ranges from decimal 0 to 255, since it unsigned.  I think putting the `U` upfront is a more common practice (`UINT8`), but if you are used to the concepts it is reasonably clear.  And of course the typedef/define is not hard to check.

---

## About `stdint.h`

Integer types are the ones with the greatest range of variation, and in fact the ISO C standard does require that an implementation include definitions for various integer types with certain *minimum* sizes in `stdint.h`.  These have names like `int_least8_t`. Of course, types with a real *fixed* size (not just a minimum) are needed for many things, and most common implementations do provide them.  The C99 standard dictates that if they are available, they should be accessible via names following the pattern `intN_t` (signed) and `uintN_t` (unsigned), where `N` is the number of bits.  The signed types are also specified as [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_complement), so one can work with such values in all kinds of highly portable ways.

As a final note, while I'm not familiar with MicroC, I would not take that documentation as representative of C generally -- it is intended for use in a somewhat restrictive and specialized environment (a 16-bit int, implied by the typedefs, is unusual, and so if you ran that code elsewhere, INT16U could be 32-bits, etc).  I'd guess MicroC only conforms to ANSI C, which is the oldest and most minimal standard; evidently it has no stdint.h.

Comment: your description of `stdint.h` goes a little bit in the wrong direction. It has both, exact-width and minimum-width integer types. Something like `uint32_t` is an exact width type, whereas `uint_least32_t` would be a type of at least 32 bits.

Comment: One could also perhaps add, that the way this is done in the cited code is obsolete and should be replaced by the types that are defined in `stdint.h`.

Comment: @goldilocks Using TI's compiler for some of their DSP's yields a 16-bit `char`  @Jens `stdint.h` mostly makes this entire custom solution unnecessary.  It looks like the actual code here is an implementation grounded in the unique properties of a given compiler, ie this is platform-specific glue to achieve a portable baseline.

Comment: @JensGustedt : I was just going with the non-optional types in 7.18 of the C99 draft.  But I've fleshed out the last paragraph(s) a bit to explain better the fixed sizes.

Comment: I don't understand your answer to question 5 @goldilocks

Comment: @ArmiaWagdy *"Possibly the author wanted to restrict the number of places such a type is defined."* -> By `#define`ing UBYTE as INT8U, if for some reason the typedef of INT8U needs to change, then UBYTE (which sounds like it also should be an unsigned 8-bit type) will also be changed automatically.  If instead you used two (identical) typedefs for both of them, you'd presumably have to change both.  Not a big deal if there are only two and you can remember both of them or include appropriate comments, but still a good idea.

Comment: I don't see any advantage in using this line `typedef unsigned char INT8U` I think it should be `typedef unsigned char UBYTE` and if for some reason the typedef of unsigned char is changed the UBYTE will also change

Comment: @ArmiaWagdy Here's an example scenario: the code has to be compiled using the TI compiler mentioned by Chris Stratton, which has a 16-bit char.  To port the code, we'll have to change `typedef unsigned char INT8U` to something else.  Let's assume TI has stdint.h, so we can use `typedef uint8_t INT8U`.  Since UBYTE is a `#define` associating it with INT8U, we don't have to change anything else.  If instead UBYTE was a separate typedef, we'd have to change that code too.  So the #define essentially says, "No matter what, both these types should be the same".

Comment: A minor detail, but otherwise we'd have to intuit more.  Lots of minor details can add up to a big hassle, and the more places where code maintenance has to rely on the intuition of the maintainer, the more potential oversights and mistakes that can occur.

Comment: for the same example and my approach if `typedef unsigned char UBYTE`
and the unsigned char is converted to say unit8_t it will be 
`typedef unit8_t UBYTE` and I don't have to change anythng else, So what is the advantage of using `#define` ,I really confused !!

Comment: Ah, but you *can't* create your own definitions of standard types (well -- you can try using stuff like `#define int int32_t`, but please don't).  Even if you could, changing the definition of `unsigned char` to suit the purposes of UBYTE would be a very bad idea, since the former is probably used for many other unrelated things.