# Combining three nibbles

Tags: c

I'm working on a code that combines nibbles. I got one working where I combine two nibbles. However, I also need to combine three nibbles into one 12 bit. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

example:

nibble 1: F

nibble 2: 1

nibble 3: 3

The result is F31.

EDIT:
As others have requested, this is my two nibbles combiner:

```
unsigned int combineBytes(unsigned lowByte, unsigned highByte){
    unsigned int combinedByte;
    combinedByte = lowByte | (highByte << 4);
    return (combinedByte);
}
```

Comment: How did you manage to combine two nibbles, and what issues did you hit trying to expand that to three nibbles?

Comment: Why does Sokoban comes to my mind reading this question?-)

Comment: @alk never heard of Sokoban until you mentioned it.

Comment: @user2989964: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban

Comment: @alk interesting. I might have played it in my childhood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int8u nibble1 = 0xF;
int8u nibble2 = 0x1;
int8u nibble3 = 0x3;
int16u combined;

combined = (nibble1 << 8) | (nibble2) | (nibble3 << 4);
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed this. I guess I was having mental blocks!

Comment: Just to check, the answer would be F31, right? Just like what I have? F is the leftmost with 8 bit shift. 1 at the right most with no bit shift and 3 at the middle with 4 bit shifts. Am I understanding this right? Thanks!

Comment: Where does `int8u` come from?

Comment: @alk ***[Here is an abscure source](http://www.ckernel.nl/index.php/the-c-kernel/binding?format=pdf)***.  And ***[here is a discussion including](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942152/how-to-make-my-data-types-independent-of-compiler-in-c)***.  Could not find any common .h files including int8u though.  Probably used a lot (by #defining using base types) in firmware or embedded work.

Comment: @ryyker You're right.  The embedded microcontroller I'm developing on right now is the STM32.  We use `typedef unsigned char int8u;` to define `int8u`.  Knowing the bit width is really important in embedded  applications.

Comment: @user2989964 Correct.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey @ryyker: Why not `uint8_t` from C99's `<stdint.h>`?

Comment: @alk As long as `stdint.h` is mapped to your microcontroller, you can use anything you want.  The point is, use the right bit width for the variable.  A nibble is only four bits, so it only requires an 8-bit data type to fit.